# I have the following index that I need to programme so for different svalues of inputs has this form

Tags: python, indexing

Does anybody know how could I make this type of index on Python?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get a matrix with values of a given sequence, shifted one item left each row. Sort of:

```py
seq = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr = [[0]*len(seq) for _ in seq]
for i in range(len(seq)):
    arr[i][:len(seq)-i] = seq[i:]
```

which results in an array

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 0],
 [3, 4, 5, 0, 0],
 [4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
 [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

If the matrix is used for calculations only and remains unchanged, then I would use `as_strided` from `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

seq = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr = np.r_[seq, np.zeros(len(seq)-1)]

itemsize = arr.dtype.itemsize
count = len(seq)

arr = as_strided(arr, shape=(count, count), strides=(itemsize, itemsize))
```

`arr` will only be twice as large as `seq`, while the view is:

```
array([[1., 2., 3., 4., 5.],
       [2., 3., 4., 5., 0.],
       [3., 4., 5., 0., 0.],
       [4., 5., 0., 0., 0.],
       [5., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```